# Can the context-sensitivity of word problem in group $G$ be equivalently characterised through some structural properties of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group, $A$ is a finite set of generators of $G$. Define $\pi: (A \cup A^{-1})^* \to G$ using the following recurrence:

$$\pi(\Lambda) = e$$
$$\pi(a \alpha) = a\pi(\alpha)$$

Now define the language $L(G, A) := \{w \in (A \cup A^{-1})^*| \pi(w) = e\}$.

It seems, that position of $L$ in Chomsky hierarchy uniquely depends on some structural properties of $G$. There are the following three theorems about that:

**Anisimov theorem**

> $L(A, G)$ is regular (type 3 in Chomsky hierarchy) iff $G$ is finite.

**Muller-Shupp theorem**

> $L(A, G)$ is context-free (type 2 in Chomsky hierarchy) iff $G$ is virtually free.

**Higman theorem**

> $L(A, G)$ is recursively enumerable (type 0 in Chomsky hierarchy) iff $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a finitely presented group.

You may have already noticed that something (and, to be exact, context-sensitive languages - type 1 in Chomsky hierarchy) is missing from the list. My question is:

> Can the condition of context-sensitivity of $L(G, A)$ also be equivalently characterised through some group-theoretic properties of $G$.

Comment: No such characterization is known, but many groups have been proved to have context-sensitive word problem. Note that this condition is equivalent to being solvable in linear space, which is a more natural class to consider froma complexity viewpoint.